# How to parse an xml node with large value?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have tried XmlReader with

```
var obj = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

But, this give the entire value of the node at once. I need to get the value in stream.

Below is the sample xml

```
<IP>
  <ALLIPsPossible>0.0.0.0 .......192.168.1.1...... 255.255.255.255(this can be in GB)</ALLIPsPossible>
</IP>
```

How to parse the value of ?

Comment: The real problem here is of course the design of this XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XmlReader.ReadValueChunk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readvaluechunk(v=vs.110).aspx), it allows you to read parts of a node's value.

```
long curr = 0;
int read = 0;
do {
    char[] buffer = new char[bufferLength];
    int read = reader.ReadValueChunk(buffer, curr, bufferLength);
    WriteData(buffer); // Do something with the data you got
} while(read == bufferLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by ' ' (SPACE) character, or any separator.
Assuming you read into `string value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();` put that string into a `StringReader` which is able to stream it.

Comment: When I say reader.ReadElementContentAsString() read the string, it is already in the memory. I must avoid that.